# Why doesn't Stack Overflow use Azure?

Tags: discussion

**Azure WebApp**, **Azure SQL Server**, **Blob Storage Accounts** etc... can [scale immensely](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/checklist/scalability), at ease, fair price and with reliable results plus their benefits like background [worker roles](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/02/29/background-business-azure-worker-role-vs-web-job/), Webjobs, [Functions](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/09/14/azure-functions-or-webjobs/), etc....

Why has Stack Overflow never given it a thought?

Instead, [StackOverflow have set up their own everything](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html), is there a reason behind this?

Comment: "Why has StackOverflow never given it a thought?" Why do you assume that's the case? The fact that the decision has been made in a way that you wouldn't expect doesn't mean it hasn't been considered.

Comment: and that's why i want to know the reasoning behind the decision...

Comment: From your link "Marco Ceccon in his talk says when talking about architecture you need to answer this question first: what kind of problem is being solved?" What kind of problem is being solve with Azure?

Comment: Then I suggest you should have phrased your question in a non-disparaging way - and done research beforehand, as I'm sure there are blog posts about this.

Comment: See comments in https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/ for example.

Comment: If you can prove that Stack Overflow can run with the matching performance for cheaper on Azure, I'm sure Nick Craver wants to talk to you. Until then, study the [hardware used to run the sites](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/), and see if Azure can match that level of power, and how much it'll cost per year to run. I'm thinking it just isn't cost effective. (Note that Nick has said as much in the comments there: *Quick bottom line: both price and performance*).

Comment: Forget about Azure, they should be using MongoDB.

Comment: @Stijn, yes...that's what i meant to say...why SQL when they have so many millions requests? i dont dispute StackOverflow is fast enough, but can something like MongoDB be like a turbo on their fast engine?

Comment: Perhaps SO don't want or need umm... 'webscale' :)

Comment: the type of an answer i expected was around this idea - "I prefer a shotgun because its stronger than a pistol and smaller than a missile".

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer is: [because Nick Craver](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/03/29/stack-overflow-the-hardware-2016-edition/) needed a [job](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/)

Seriously, tho, as someone who does full stack, the reason is that there's not a one-size-fits-all hosting scheme for everyone. I use AWS. We've used it since before Azure. There's no reason to switch AFAIK, and it would be a pain to abandon the tried and true business practices we've developed over the years. Clearly SO has put some serious thought and effort behind their platform and selected what is best for them as a company.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Machavity. The thing is, i use Azure alot, and i don't see it missing anything that StackOverflow requires, at a cheaper cost. I understand that you cant just change the current architecture for the sake of a platform, but still... if they were to consider, would they still choose their current architecture?

Comment: @McKabue The mistake you're making is that you're assuming the cost of the equipment is the only concern. Would they still pick a colocation rack with metal server now? No clue. But hardware cost should never be your only concern.